# Best way to handle missing data for Network Modelling?

Tags: missing-data, bayesian-network, multiple-imputation

I'm planning to undertake Network Modelling. However, I've been told that multiple imputation is a problem for Network Modelling. I have a lot of missing data. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution, check out the [structural EM](https://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/structural.em.html) in the {bnlearn} package in R.

Answer (score 1):

For network modelling, referring to imputing for set of [adjacency matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) representing Network; there are couple of high-quality multiple imputation approach one could take, such as MICE, see [Multiple imputation by chained equations: what is it and how does it work?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3074241/). The difficulty is that if you have multiple features on nodes, one would need to pre-process imputation in such a way to represent data meaningfully to process with MICE, for example it could mean that impute missing data in series of adjacency "feature" matrices.

Let's say we have 3 nodes and each node has two features, so that one would construct 3 matrices $C$ for connectivity, $F_{1}$ feature values on $C$ for the feature 1 and  $F_{2}$ feature values on $C$ for the feature 2, all having $3x9$ size and possibly missing features on $F_{1}$ and $F_{2}$.

Comment: That's really helpful - thank you! Do you know how I can combine all the imputed sets for network modelling? e.g., Is there a function in R for this?

Comment: There is an implementation of [MICE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf). You could also browse the task view on network modelling [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. There is the pool() function in MICE but I don't think it works for network modelling. I can potentially use a long format to include all multiply imputed data but my worry is that I may end up artificially inflating the sample size. I can potentially use only one of the imputed datasets using the complete () function but this may cause other issues. I'm really new to this so have no idea what to do in this case. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: MICE is for imputation only. From the package 'mice' would do the imputation on connectivity/features, data.